# Keras Model predicts NaN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a model for my binary classification problem.

My data has 91 columns and 50 thousand rows. One of the columns is my binary target variable and all the others are also numeric. Here is how I tried to train ;

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=90, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=20)
```

After a fast training, I tried to predict with my test set and saw that all predictions are `NaN`

```
+ model.predict(x_test_scaled)

- array([[nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       ...,
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan]], dtype=float32)
```

By the way, I also didn't see loss score during training. There was also written `NaN`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually happens because of `NaNs/infinity` in your dataset. You should consider dropping such rows during pre-processing.

The below code will return `True` if all the values are finite.

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df).all(1)]
```

If it returns `False` you might have to drop NaN/infinity

```
# Replacing infinite with nan 
df.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True) 

# Dropping all the rows with nan values 
df.dropna(inplace=True) 

# Printing df 
df
```

Sometimes Changing the optimizer to `RMSprop` solves the issue

Comment: thank you, my dataset didn't have infinite values. changing optimizer to RMSprop fixed my problem.

Comment: @VidyaGanesh good suggestion of using `RMSprop` probably there might be a problem with exploding gradients and RMSProp will definitely help with that ;)