# Keras model predict has nan loss and predict nan values

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I faced the same issue as this question: [Keras Model predicts NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080745/keras-model-predicts-nan). But the solutions in this answer does not help me.

I have this model:

```
inp_fea = layers.Input((16,16,512))

# put the features as the input of MLP, then construst the MLP classifier
flat = layers.Flatten()(inp_fea)
fc_256 = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(flat)
fc_10 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(fc_256)

# model: VGG_extracted_features -> Faltten -> FC256 -> FC10
final_model = Model(inp_fea, fc_10)
```

And compile it like this:

```
# set optimiser
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
# compile model
final_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fit the model:

```
final_model_history = final_model.fit(train_imgs_fea, train_labels_int_np, epochs=20, batch_size=32)
```

And get this:
[image]

Predict the training dataset `final_model.predict(train_imgs_fea)` gets this:

[image]

Note that my `train_imgs_fea` has shape (7500, 16, 16, 512)

I have tried two things as suggested in [Keras Model predicts NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080745/keras-model-predicts-nan):

1. Change optimiser to RMSprop -> result in the same scenario
2. Check whether there are infinite values in `train_imgs_fea` by: `False in np.isfinite(train_imgs_fea)`, which returns `False`

Any helps are appreciated!

Comment: what's the shape of `train_labels_int_np`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class_count=10 # number of classes
img_shape=(16,16,512)
base_model=tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False, weights="imagenet",input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max') 
x=base_model.output
x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
x = Dense(256, kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(l = 0.016),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006),
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.006) ,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(rate=.45, seed=123)(x)        
output=Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(x)
final_model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
final_model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001), loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

You are using SparseCategoricalCrossentropy so your labels should be integers.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Gerry! I was about to try your solution, and then discovered that restarting the kernel magically works...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to close my jupyter notebook and restart my kernel, then it magically worked.